# Redireccion 301 arrastra la variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Estoy creando algunas redirecciones 301 en uno de mis sitios, para eliminar URLs indexadas y dejarla un poco más optimizado.

Bien, si hago redirecciones entre etiquetas por ejemplo:

```
redirect 301 /videos/coche-electrico.html https://www.dominio.com/videos/coches-electricos.html
```

Funciona bien, es decir hace la redirección correctamente. El problema que tengo es cuando intento hacer una redirección parecida, pero en lugar de redireccionar entre etiquetas como el caso anterior, intento hacerlo de etiqueta a categoría. Es decir:

```
redirect 301 /videos/coche-electrico.html https://www.dominio.com/categoria/coches-electricos/
```

Haciéndome la redirección de este tipo:

> ```
> https://www.dominio .com/categoria/coches-electricos/?tag=coche-electrico
> ```

Parte del código del .htaccess es este:

```
Rewriterule ^videos/(.)_(.).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]
```

También he probado de aislar el problema y hacerlo solamente así:

```
RewriteRule ^clientes/(\w+)/?$ clientes.php?id=$1 [L]
Redirect 301 /clientes/juan http://google.es
```

Y la redirección que hace en este caso en google, también arrastra el **`id=juan`**:

```
https://www.google.es/?id=juan&gws_rd=ssl
```

¿A alguien se lo ocurre cómo puedo hacer la redirección sin pasar ningún parámetro o valor, dejando la redirección limpia?

> ```
> https://www.dominio.com/categoria/coches-electricos/
> ```

Comment: Una recomendación: **no uses la redirección 301 hasta que estés 100% segur@ de que es la redirección correcta que quieres hacer**. Las redirecciones 301 son permanentes, los navegadores las cachean y es difícil hacer que las dejen de usar. Usa 302 mientras haces pruebas y sólo pasa a las 301 cuando vayas a realizar los cambios definitivamente.

Comment: Gracias alvaro, lo tendre en cuenta, pero de momento estoy probando con un solo tag a ver si lo consigo solucionar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la opción del guión del RewriteRule

Añade esto delante de todos tus RewriteRule para que los siguientes RewriteRule no sean ejecutados cuando cumplan las condiciones.

```
RewriteRule ^/videos/coche-electrico.html$ - [L]
```

Lo que hace esa instrucción es que en caso de encontrar lo que está buscando **NO** lo modificará (el guión hace eso) y luego con el [L] le dices que ya no ejecute más RewriteRules.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, pero esto tampoco me han funcionado, me da error de servidor

Comment: A ver, releyendo ahora la pregunta (lo de clientes creo que sobra) no me queda claro lo que quieres exactamente. Por favor, modifica la pregunta y pon exactamente que quieres reescribir y a donde lo quieres enviar. Y añade como tienes ahora el .htaccess porque como bien te respondí el orden de las reglas es importante ya que unas pueden evitar que las otras hagan su función, de ahí el recomendarte utilizar el guión para que no procesase más reglas.

Answer (score 0):

Apache agrega los parámetros de búsqueda cuando no se especifica ninguno. Por lo que se puede:

1. Configurar un nuevo parámetro vacío (el `?` al final).

   ```py
   Redirect 302 /videos/coche-electrico.html https://url.com/aaa/bbb/?
   ```

2. Usar [`[QSD]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) (*query string discard*) para definir que se eliminen.

   ```py
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^videos/coche-electrico\.html$ https://url.com/aaa/bbb/ [R=302,NC,L,QSD]
   ```

Comment: hola, he probado estos dos ejemplos, y tampoco hace la redirección que intento hacer.

Comment: @vpme si no te funciona, el error está en otro lado. Si no redirecciona, hay algo que no está habilitado para que funcione el .htaccess. Si te da un error 503, tenés algún error en alguna otra línea del .htaccess, o no habilitaste algún módulo.

Comment: Si la redirección la hago hacia una pagina .html si que funciona, pero si la hago en la categoria directamente y acabando en / no funciona y arrastra el valor.

Comment: @vpme Por supuesto, si con la única URL que coincide esta regla es con `/videos/coche-electrico.html` ... Eso es lo que preguntaste. La idea es que apliques esta lógica al resto de tus reglas... Si hay una regla que no te está funcionando, podés formular una nueva pregunta especificando claramente cuál es la URL original, a qué URL tiene que redireccionar y con qué está fallando.

Comment: ya he vuelto a formular la pregunta a ver si ahora se entiende mejor mi intención. muchas gracias -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/83211/46275