# Redireccionamiento 301 mediante htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirección, mod-rewrite

Tengo un problema con unas redirecciones en un site a la hora de crear una redirección de una `<etiqueta>.html` a una `<categoria>/`. El problema es que arrastra la variable.

Las `<etiqueta>`s son una lista predefinida por mí (no es cualquier texto).

#### Ejemplo 1

- URL original en la petición:

  ```
  dominio.com/videos/coches-electricos.html
  ```
- URL a la cual debe redireccionar:

  ```
  dominio.com/gratis/coches-electricos/
  ```
- Y debe reescribirla para acceder al recurso (eliminando todos los parámetros GET que pudiera tener) a:

  ```
  dominio.com/index.php?cat=coches-electricos
  ```

#### Ejemplo 2

y quiero que sea:

```
https://www.dominio.com/gratis/coches-electricos/
```

redireccionada a:

```
https://www.dominio.com/categoria/coches-electricos/?tag=coche-electrico
```

#### Código

El **código htaccess** para crear el mod rewrite que estoy usando es:

```
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^gratis-(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^gratis/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^gratis/(.*)/$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

y para crear la redirección 301 estoy usando:

```
redirect 301 /videos/coches-electricos.html https://www.dominio.com/gratis/coches-electricos/
```

Comment: Debe ser la 10ma vez que leo el planteo y sigue sin quedarme claro. En tu ejemplo, ¿cuál es la URL a la que accede el usuario? (la URL que escribe en el navegador, antes de que se aplique cualquier regla)

Comment: el usuario escribiría en el navegador: dominio .com/videos/coches-electricos.html y esta debería redireccionar a /gratis/coches-electricos/

Comment: Bien, ¿es sólo para `coches-electricos`, o es para cualquier nombre, es decir para cualquier `<etiqueta>.html`?

Comment: la idea es ir haciendo redirecciones según vaya viendo que etiquetas redireccionar, es decir NO redireccionar todo de <etiqueta>.html sino en algunos casos. me explico?

Comment: Perfecto, y luego de la **redirección**, además, debería quedar `/gratis/coches-electricos/` como URL final, pero debería **reescribir** a `/index.php?cat=coches-electricos` ? (es decir, el usuario no ve eso, pero accede al index del root con ese parámetro)

Comment: Exacto! internamente el usuario accede desde esa url sin mod_rewrite

Comment: (De hecho, al **reescribir**, se debe usar `mod_rewrite`). Lo que no termino de entender es en qué parte de todo esto entra en juego la URL `https://www.dominio.com/categoria/coches-electricos/?tag=coche-electrico`

Comment: Edité la pregunta con toda esta información. Por favor revisa si está bien. El **ejemplo 2**, simplemente no me queda claro cómo debería ser.

Comment: El ejemplo 2, es lo que me devuelve al hacer una redirección normal redirect 301 /videos/coches-electricos.html https://www.dominio.com/gratis/coches-electricos/ que haciendolo asi, es como si arrastrase el tag. he realizado una prueba fuera de la web.

RewriteRule ^clientes/(\w+)/?$ clientes.php?id=$1 [L]
Redirect 301 /clientes/juan http://google.es 

y con este codigo tambien me devuelve https://www.google.es/?id=juan

Comment: Sigo sin entender ese ejemplo 2. Publiqué lo que resuelve al ejemplo 1. Si hay algo del ejemplo 2 que me falte, lo ideal sería [edit] la pregunta, siguiendo el mismo formato que usé para el ejemplo 1, en el ejemplo 2.

Answer (score 2):

Se pueden poner todas las redirecciones al inicio:

```
Redirect 302 /videos/coches-electricos.html /gratis/coches-electricos/
Redirect 302 /videos/bici.html              /gratis/bici/
Redirect 302 /videos/mecano.html            /gratis/mecano/
```

- Fijate que estoy usando una redirección 302. El tema es así: **jamás** uses un 301 para probar algo porque cualquier error puede llegar a quedar en caché (de alguno de los nodos o de tu navegador). Siempre con 302. Una vez que estés más que completamente seguro de que funciona como querés **y que no lo vas a modificar jamás** en el futuro, recién ahí podrías cambiarlo a 301.

El resto de las reglas de reescritura se seguirían aplicando. Me tomé a libertad de agruparlas un poco.

```py
RewriteEngine on

# REDIRECCiÓN
# (probalo con 302, si funciona se cambia a 301 -nunca jamás uses un 301 hasta estar convencido)
# Redirecciona un listado de posibles tags (descarta parámetros GET)
Redirect 302 /videos/coches-electricos.html /gratis/coches-electricos/?
Redirect 302 /videos/bici.html              /gratis/bici/?
Redirect 302 /videos/mecano.html            /gratis/mecano/?


# esta es otra forma de redireccionar a 1 solo
# RewriteRule ^videos/(coches-electricos)\.html$ gratis/$1/ [R=302,NC,QSD]

# o si se prefiere, a todos juntos:
# RewriteRule ^videos/(coches-electricos|bici|mecano)\.html$ gratis/$1/ [R=302,NC,QSD]


# REESCRITURA
Rewriterule ^videos/([^_/]*)(?:_([^/]*))?\.html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^gratis(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?|-([^/]+)\.html)$ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2$3 [L,NC]
```

---

Subí una demo a un hosting gratuito con este mismo .htaccess. Se puede probar:

1. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/videos/coches-electricos.html (redirecciona)
2. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/videos/bici.html (esta está en la lista de las que redirecciona)
3. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/videos/una-etiqueta_una-pagina.html
4. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/videos/una-etiqueta.html
5. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/gratis/una-categoria/
6. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/gratis/una-categoria/una-pagina/
7. http://mariano.uphero.com/83211/gratis-foo.html

Comment: el problema es que tengo muchos a editar, no se podría hacer como las otras redirecciones

redirect 301 /videos/bici.html https://www.dominio/gratis/bici/
redirect 301 /videos/mecano.html https://www.dominio/gratis/mecanico/

Si tener que tener en una misma linea todas las palabras juntas ( que no son pocas las que tengo que redireccionar ) y asi evitar de editar la regla del mod_rewrite para evitar posibles fallos en las etiquetas que SI funcionan correctamente.
solo tengo que redireccionar algunas de las <etiquetas>.html a <categorias>/ y no todas las que estas en <etiquetas>

Comment: @vpme Sí, claro que se puede. Da igual cómo lo hagas. Editado.